# UIButton `setTitleShadowColor:ForState` not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2

I have a UICollectionView with a CustomCollectionViewCell class.
Inside the cell I have a button I did set with storyboard. I want the button to change its color when tapped, but I keep getting something like the shadow of the title with a different blue color than the background  when selected.

I've tried fixing it with `setTitleShadowColor:ForState` with `.Selected` and `.Normal`. But it doesn't seems to do anything.

ViewController:

```
...
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfButtons
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.setContents(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
...
```

CustomCollectionViewCell:

```
...
func setContents(row: Int) {
    buttonInCell.setTitle(String(row + 1), forState: .Normal)
    buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonInCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    buttonInCell.layer.cornerRadius = buttonRadius
    buttonInCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    buttonInCell.layer.borderWidth = buttonBorderWidth
}

func changeButtonStatus(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.selected {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        sender.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    } else {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        sender.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    }
}
// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func buttonInCellTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    changeButtonStatus(sender)
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution just changing the button type as "custom" in the attributes inspector in Xcode.